# Can't make dictionary from txt file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

So I defined a blank dictionary called **library** globally. I already know how to save a dictionary to a txt file.

The output of the txt file looks like this this (it's called **bookList0.txt**):

```
{'Hobbit': {'author': 'J.R.R.Tolkien', 'year': '1937', 'genre': 'fantasy'}}
```

I made a function to load this file:

```
 library = {}
 def load():
    print("Loading library..")
    f = open("bookList0.txt", "r")
    library = eval(f.readline())
    if len(library) > 0:
        print("Library successfully loaded!")
    else:
        print("Library didn't load!")
```

If i use this function it says "Library successfully loaded!". But when i type `print(library)` in the console it only shows `{}`.

However, if i type `f = open(str("bookList0.txt"), "r")` then `library = eval(f.readline())` in the console and then again `print(library)` in the console it gives me the dictionary that is in the file. So that way it works.

And i don't know why is this not working in a function, but works in the console. Thanks for the help!

**Update:** I tried loading with the json module but still it doesn't load anything. Here's the code that i wrote for json:

```
json_file = open("bookList.json")
json_str = str(json_file.read())
json_data = json.loads(json_str)
library = json_data
```

**Problem solved!** This is the code that seems to be working:

```
def load():
    print("Loading library..")
    json_file = open("bookList.json")
    json_str = str(json_file.read())
    json_data = json.loads(json_str)
    library.update(json_data)
    if len(library) > 0:
        print("Library successfully loaded!")
    else:
        print("Library didn't load!")
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `eval`, have a look at [the json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: [mcve], please. (i.e. show us where you put that `print(library)` that you claim produces incorrect output)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille in this case given the quoting - `ast.literal_eval` is probably better...

Comment: You should use the JSON module with `loads` and `dumps` function to handle encoding/decoding dicts

Comment: Try capturing the line, and printing it before making the dict.  It sounds like there are some empty lines in the file.

Comment: @Aran-Frey I typed `print(library)` into the console

Comment: @Barnistic Ok, but your `load` function doesn't return anything, so `print(library)` should throw a NameError in the console. Unless you've previously defined a global variable named `library`. So I repeat my request for a MCVE.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I did an MCVE.

Comment: json.loads(string) is preferred

Comment: Are you sure that your file and console are running in the same directory? It might very well be that there are two different `bookList0.txt` files.

Comment: @palivek Yes, they are in the same directory.

Comment: You expect that an object (the dictionary) that in the function `load` is bound to the name `library` is bound to the same name in the calling level (in your case, the console).  But it is not like that!!! There are exceptions to this simple rule but  the calling level usually knows only what a function `return`s, like in `library = load() ; print(library)` (with the provision that you modify `load` inserting a `return library` statement)

Comment: _Yes, they are in the same directory._ you say. In that case, @Aran-Fey's argument stands: you haven't provided an MCVE, becuase the fault is not in the code you've provided.

Comment: The code that "seems to work" cannot possibly work because you can't call `library.update(...)` without defining a `library` variable first. All of the code you posted is missing some parts.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have not a clear understanding of Python's [name scopes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

I have written a little script where I have (*mutatis mutandis*, i.e., no external files involved...) two different `load` definitions, `load_01` that, like in your code, has no `return` statement and `load_02` that has a `return` statement, and where I have invoked in different ways these two functions, i.e., without or with a corresponding assignment, and in each of these four cases the script prints its idea of the value of `library`.

```
$ cat delendo.py
library = {}
data = '''{
    'Hobbit': 
        {'author': 'J.R.R.Tolkien', 'year': '1937', 'genre': 'fantasy'}}'''

def load_01(s):
    library = eval(s)
    print('Loaded 01')

def load_02(s):
    library = eval(s)
    print('Loaded 02')
    return library

print('='*64)
print('Initial value of _library_')
print(library)

print('='*64)
print('No return, no assignment')
load_01(data) ; print(library)
print('No return, assignment')
library = load_01(data) ; print(library)

print('='*64)
print('Reset value of _library_')
library = {}
print(library)

print('='*64)
print('Return, no assignment')
load_02(data) ; print(library)
print('Return, assignment')
library = load_02(data) ; print(library)
```

Here I have the results of executing the script that I have prepared

```
$ python delendo.py 
================================================================
Initial value of _library_
{}
================================================================
No return, no assignment
Loaded 01
{}
No return, assignment
Loaded 01
None
================================================================
Reset value of _library_
{}
================================================================
Return, no assignment
Loaded 02
{}
Return, assignment
Loaded 02
{'Hobbit': {'author': 'J.R.R.Tolkien', 'year': '1937', 'genre': 'fantasy'}}
$
```

I hope that, studying the code and confronting with the output, you could get a better understanding of name scopes in Python.

---

ps, all that was told in comments, about the use of `eval` and the opportunity of using the `json` module stands on its own and you should try to incorporate the suggestions you've received in your code.

My example is only addressed to one side  of the problems you're facing, namely the one that puzzles you at the moment...